# Chatter publisher action + canvas app: cancel publishing?

Tags: canvas, publisher-action

Canvas SDK documentation pretty [clearly describes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_sdk_publisher_events.htm) the canvas app event flow in case user wishes to share something:

```
Sfdc.canvas.client.subscribe(sr.client,
{
    name: "publisher.getPayload", onData: function (event)
    {
        var post = {};

        post.feedItemType = "LinkPost";
        post.url = url;
        post.urlName = urlName;

        Sfdc.canvas.client.publish(sr.client,
            { name: "publisher.setPayload", payload: post });
    }
});
```

But is there an event or a method (that canvas app can fire) to either

- cancel the publishing action inside the `publisher.getPayload` handler, or
- reset the state of a publisher canvas (clearing the "Share an update..." part, etc)?